# How is Arithmetic different in regards to the definition than the alternative

Tags: arithmetic

Good day all,

My first post 14 hours ago was an inquiry about how I can develop a solid foundation in understanding and applying mathematics to life.

Having got three good responses I've opened up an ages old photo-copied book which I believe will aid me further in my journey.

So I started reading and come to realize I don't understand what Arithmetic means or is.

When I googled for the derivation of it so as to see where the word derives from I ended up finding the definition instead: "the branch of mathematics dealing with the properties and manipulation of numbers."

So I ask, what branches are there in mathematics that *deviates* from dealing with properties and the manipulation of numbers ?

Is the definition incorrect, am I misunderstanding it ?

Comment: Mathematical logic is a branch of mathematics that doesn’t deal with numbers

Comment: Most branches?  Graph theory, topology, and knot theory to name a few... You could argue that even enumerative combinatorics doesn't.  Granted in some fields which aren't called arithmetic, one might *use* arithmetic to complete certain tasks... but the focus of one's attention in the study of those fields is certainly not the arithmetic itself.  Arithmetic in those fields is just a tool to advance from one step in the process to the next.

Comment: How about geometry?